# THREE JS destroy scene and removing form RAM

Tags: javascript, three.js

There is a bunch of practices, how to **destroy** whole **THREE.js scene**.
I tried all of them. I still cannot remove a scene from RAM usage of a web browser. Which makes me a problem. Using THREE.js to generate scene with performance needed effects to create a simple snapshot (scene is not animated). After that i need to remove all scene data. Eventually I can do it a many times, this is why i need exactly remove scene from browser memory. But actually I get memory leak in all browsers and all machines i used to testing with no performance dependency.

**This is how I remove scene:**

```
                          THREEEnemyShipScene.clearScene = function (obj) {
                                    if (obj instanceof THREE.Mesh && obj.type == "Mesh")
                                    {

                                        obj.geometry.dispose();
                                        obj.geometry = null;
                                        obj.material.dispose();
                                        obj.material = null;
                                        scene.remove( obj ),
                                        obj = null;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (obj.children !== undefined) {
                                            while (obj.children.length > 0) {
                                                this.clearScene(obj.children[0]);
                                                obj.remove(obj.children[0]);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                          THREEEnemyShipScene.remove = function () {
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.clearScene(THREEEnemyShipScene.scene);
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.renderer = null;

                              THREEEnemyShipScene.scene = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.canvas = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.camera = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.light = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.render = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.shipBox = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.corplogo = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.ModelLength = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.postprocessing.scene = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.postprocessing.bokeh_uniforms = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.postprocessing.camera = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.postprocessing.materialBokeh = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.postprocessing.quad = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.postprocessing.rtTextureColor = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.postprocessing.rtTextureDepth = null;
                              THREEEnemyShipScene.postprocessing = null;
                          }
```

After it the scene is removed, but a browser memory is still allocated. After 5 minutes waiting on garbage collector, memory is still not released.

I understand, i need to remove all the references to object to remove it completely. What I'm doing wrong? Any better ideas to release scene and scene children from memory?

Comment: call delete explicitly